# Has the used of Solidity in Ethereum gone down over time?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, vyper

I am getting started learning Solidity for Ethereum contracts. But I worry that Solidity could be displaced by other smart language contracts, or even languages like Python or Go.

Comment: Solidity is the most dominant, idk what you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about. Solidity is the most used language for developing smart contracts out there.

It's used not only in the Ethereum network but on all EVM-based blockchain networks, such as Binance, Avalance, RSK, etc. See the complete list of EVM-based networks here: https://chainlist.org/

Other blockchains use different languages, like Solana which uses Rust for its smart contracts.

Solidity is still going strong and its future looks promising with all the updates that it is being added.

Since the syntax of Solidity looks much like languages like Java and Javascript, many developers already familiar with C-like languages find it really easy to start coding in Solidity.